# Google App Engine DB doesn't execute to completion before returning

Tags: python, sql, database, google-app-engine

I'm currently working with Google app engine's built-in db. It seems that when I run `put()` to insert a tuple into the database, the function returns even though the tuple has not yet been completely inserted. Here's the code:

```
new_user = Users(username=username_input, hashed_password=get_hashed_password(username_input, password))
new_user.put()

existing_user = None
while not existing_user:    
        print "existing_user still not in DB"

        #tries to get the user that was put into the DB
        existing_user = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username=:username_input", username_input=username_input).get()
print "existing_user in DB"
```

When I run this code, I get the following output,

```
existing_user still not in DB
existing_user still not in DB
existing_user still not in DB
existing_user still not in DB
existing_user still not in DB
existing_user still not in DB
existing_user still not in DB
existing_user still not in DB
existing_user in DB
```

Why is this the case? Shouldn't `put()` finish putting the tuple into the DB before returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datastore is 'eventually consistent'. This means that after changes (inserts/updates/deletes), queries can (will) return an old view of the data for a short time. Using the SDK this is simulated by a delay of 1 second. In the live environment, it is *typically* less than this, but occasionally more.

To get a consistent view of the data, you either need to fetch entities directly using their key, or group your entities under a parent (put them in an entity group), and then use queries with ancestor constraints.

You can read more [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/data-consistency#data_consistency_levels) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency).